# Combining two for-loops that share similar properties

Tags: javascript, loops, dom, conditional-statements

I have two divs which numerically represent the width and height of the window's screen, counting from every 100th pixel. The numeric values are wrapped inside span tags and inserted into their respective div container through two loops. Since both of these loops share almost the same exact methods and conditional logic I was wondering if there was a way that I could combine them somehow:

**HTML**

```
<div class="rule rule--horizontal"></div>
<div class="rule rule--vertical"></div>
```

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var horizontal = document.getElementsByClassName("rule--horizontal")[0],
      vertical   = document.getElementsByClassName("rule--vertical")[0];

  for (var i = 50, screenWidth = screen.width; i < screenWidth; i+= 50) {
    if (i % 100 === 0) {
      horizontal.innerHTML += "<span class='num num--visible'>" + i + "</span>";
    }
  }

  for (var i = 50, screenHeight = screen.height; i < screenHeight; i+= 50) {
    if (i % 100 === 0) {
      vertical.innerHTML += "<span class='num num--visible'>" + i + "</span>";
    }
  }
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pL289rhv/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produce the same result

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var horizontal = document.getElementsByClassName("rule--horizontal")[0],
        vertical   = document.getElementsByClassName("rule--vertical")[0];
    var a = screen.width > screen.height ? screen.width : screen.height;
    for (var i = 50; i < a; i+= 50) {
        if (i % 100 === 0) {
            if(i < screen.width)horizontal.innerHTML += "<span class='num num--visible'>" + i + "</span>";
            if(i < screen.height)vertical.innerHTML += "<span class='num num--visible'>" + i + "</span>";
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create function and use it in two places:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var horizontal = document.getElementsByClassName("rule--horizontal")[0],
      vertical   = document.getElementsByClassName("rule--vertical")[0];
  loop(horizontal, screen.width);
  loop(vertical, screen.height);

});
function loop(element, max) {
  for (var i = 50; i < max; i+= 50) {
    if (i % 100 === 0) {
      element.innerHTML += "<span class='num num--visible'>" + i + "</span>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @ScottHunter you don't need two index variables.

Comment: @ScottHunter you don't need two index variables.

Comment: @ScottHunter I take it that you were the one to downvote the answer. Not particularly an issue but do you find it wrong now? It seems like he didn't have a chance to revise his answer 30s after posting.

Comment: @jcubic Hypothetically speaking wouldn't this still be looping twice?

Comment: @CarlEdwards: Not just hypothetically :)  But it is only *written* once; it wasn't clear from the original question if that would be acceptable.

Comment: @CarlEdwards You have to loop twice unless you want to add in a bunch of checks to see if your iterating variable is still valid. for example height = 300 and width = 500 you would have to make sure that you don't add a div for height when width is 400 and 500

Comment: @TommyDDD: No, you don't.  See user3468982's answer.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thats exactly what I meant. He has to do a bunch of checks. Its not very elegant and unless you have a screen that is billions of pixels wide and tall there is no benefit to doing it this way.

Comment: Elegance is in the eye of the beholder.  There are extra "checks" inside the loop, but because the loop gets run once instead of twice, the "checks" to control the loop get executed about half as much, so its pretty much a wash (and if you take advantage of computing the string to be concatenated and use that in the two `if`s instead of recomputing it, you get that savings, too).

Answer (score 1):

You can factor out the if statement if (i % 100 === 0) this is true on 100, 200, etc. Just start i at 100 and increment by 100

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   var horizontal = document.getElementsByClassName("rule--horizontal")[0],
       vertical   = document.getElementsByClassName("rule--vertical")[0];

   var createDivs = function (axis, maxSize) {
       for (var i = 100; i < maxSize; i += 100) {
           axis.innerHTML += "<span class='num num--visible'>" + i + "</span>";
       }
   };

   createDivs(horizontal, screen.width);
   createDivs(vertical, screen.height);
});
```